# Complement of a symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently had a test where one of the T/F questions had this option:

$\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \overline{A\triangle B}$ ,

Then, reasoning as follows:

$$x\in \overline{A\triangle B} \iff x\in \overline{\left[(A\cap\bar{B})\cup(\bar{A}\cap B)\right]} \iff x\in\left[(\bar{A}\cup B)\cap(A\cup \bar{B})\right]$$

But $x\in \overline{A\cup B}$ is equivalent to $x\in\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$, which implies $x\in\bar{A}\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup \bar{B}$, so then the condition of belonging to $\overline{A\triangle B}$ is fulfilled.

Is there any flaw with the reasoning?

Comment: It seems correct

Comment: Your proof is correct. Personally I would rather go for applicaton of $U\subseteq V\implies V^c\subseteq U^c$ for the sets $U=A\Delta B$ and $V=A\cup B$.